# Rails: Send a file generated by an axlsx view to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I am using the [axlsx](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) gem to generate excel spreadsheets. I am trying to send the generated spreadsheet to the model for zipping. This method zips the excel file with some other files.

The method in my model looks like this:

```
def zipper
  tempfile = Tempfile.new
  children = self.children_with_forms

   Zip::OutputStream.open(tempfile) do |stream|
    children.each do |child|
      directory = "#{child.wide_reference[0,3]}/"

      if child.model_name == "Position"
        stream.put_next_entry("#{child.volume} #{child.title} TOC.xlsx")
        stream.print IO.read(Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.toc_path(format: :xlsx, position_id: child.id))
      end

      stream.put_next_entry("#{directory}#{child.wide_reference}-#{child.short_name}-#{child.title.truncate(15, omission:'')}.docx")
      stream.print IO.read(child.download_form.path)
    end  
  end

  tempfile
end
```

The part I am having problems with is :

```
  if child.model_name == "Position"
    stream.put_next_entry("#{child.volume} #{child.title} TOC.xlsx")
    stream.print IO.read(Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.toc_path(format: :xlsx, position_id: child.id))
  end
```

How do I get the generated file to the model?

Comment: agustaf, you should post your final solution here and mark your own answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to render the view from inside the model using: `ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {key: value})`, thanks to the help I received [here](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails/issues/53).

Below is what ended up working.

```
def download
  tempfile = Tempfile.new
  children = self.children_with_forms
   Zip::OutputStream.open(tempfile) do |stream|
    children.each do |child|
      directory = "#{child.wide_reference[0,3]}/"
      if child.model_name == "Position"
        av = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {position: child, model: child.model})
        stream.put_next_entry("#{directory}#{child.volume} #{child.title} TOC.xlsx")
        @position = child
        @model = child.model
        stream.print av.render template: 'pages/toc.xlsx.axlsx'
      end
      stream.put_next_entry("#{directory}#{child.wide_reference} #{child.title.truncate(15, omission:'')} (#{child.short_name}).docx")
      stream.print IO.read(child.download_form.path)
    end
    stream.put_next_entry("Excel File.xlsx")
    av = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {model: self})
    stream.print av.render template: 'pages/excel_file.xlsx.axlsx'
  end
  tempfile
end
```

**NOTE:** "Model" is the name of the class that this method is in.