# Save generated excel with axlsx_rails in a folder of my project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, xlsx, axlsx

I actually can generate an excel and show the download link to the client but also I want that the file stay in a folder of my project in my server, my code is this

**Controller**

```
def generate_report
  render xlsx: 'prueba',template: 'admin/client_reports/report_a.xlsx.axlsx', filename: "a.xlsx", disposition: 'inline',
  xlsx_created_at: 3.days.ago, xlsx_author: "Elmer Fudd"
end
```

**View** `.xlsx.axlsx`

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook

wb.add_worksheet(name: "A") do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row ["Titulo", "Precio"]
end
```

I don't know how to save the excel generated in a folder of my project, too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are *always* saving the file, you can cheat and place this at the end of your xlsx.axlsx template:

```
xlsx_package.serialize(file_name)
```

Or, in the controller you can render it to string, and then serve that string as data as well as write to a file (untested code):

```
data = render_to_string handlers: [:axlsx], formats: [:xlsx], template: 'admin/client_reports/report_a.xlsx.axlsx'
File.open("/file/path/and/name.xlsx","w") {|f| f.write(data) }
send_data data, filename: "prueba.xlsx", type: Mime[:xlsx], disposition: 'inline'
```

You may or may not need the handlers / formats specified since your request is already xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing your application, so one common option to save your files is by using a file-management solution like Carrierwave. Which means that you will need to create a new model, something like `ExcelAttachments`, which can `belong_to :user`. You then can start saving your files on that model.

To do that, you might have to use `Tempfile` class (google it) and stream your AXLSX content into it, and return the file into CW. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194729/rails-send-a-file-generated-by-an-axlsx-view-to-a-model) answer might be a good place to start.